# On vanishing of global sections of some line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface $S$ in $\mathbb P^3$. Let $C$ be a smooth hyperplane section of $S$ and $D$ be a non-zero divisor on $S$. Consider the short exact sequence : $0 \to \mathcal O_S(D-(m+1)C) \to \mathcal O_S(D-mC) \to \mathcal O_C(D-mC) \to 0$. In this context my question is the following :

If we know that $h^0(\mathcal O_C(D)) <h^0(\mathcal O_C(mC))$, then can we say $h^0(O_C(D-mC))=0$?

Any remark or insight from anyone is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D'$ is an effective divisor, the morphism
$$
H^0(\mathcal{O}(D'')) \to H^0(\mathcal{O}(D' + D''))
$$
given by $D'$ is injective for any divisor class $D''$; in paricular
$$
\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}(D'')) \le \dim H^0(\mathcal{O}(D' + D'')).
$$
Now apply this observation for $D'' = mC$ and $D'$ any divisor in $|D - mC|$.

Comment: If we take $D'=D-mC$ (let's assume that this $D'$ is effective), then from your proof we have $h^0(\mathcal O_S(mC)) \leq h^0(\mathcal O_S(D))$. Could you please briefly explain how this coupled with the information $h^0(\mathcal O_C(D)) <h^0(\mathcal O_C(mC))$ gives us $h^0(\mathcal O_C(D-mC))=0$?

Comment: Instead of doing this on $S$, work on $C$.

Comment: Do you mean If $h^0(\mathcal O_C(D-mC)) \neq 0$, then from your argument we end up having $h^0(\mathcal O_C(mC)) \leq h^0(\mathcal O_C(D))$, a contradiction to the assumption that $h^0(\mathcal O_C(D)) <h^0(\mathcal O_C(mC))$?